# Pickup runs only with the ground wire removed

Tags: ford, f-150, ground

My 2006 Ford F150 would not start and the lights flashed in the dash when I tried to start it.  I removed the starter which is only 4 months old, it bench tested as perfect.  I removed the battery which is only 10 months old and took it to a shop to be tested.  All cells are 100% and it holds a charge fine.

I tried to run a new ground wire from the battery to the starter.  No change!  I checked the continuity of the ground wire in the car and I got 0.5 to 0.9 fluctuating.

Next I wanted to test the voltage drop when the starter clicking.  But I forgot to reconnect the ground wire and it started.  It started without any ground to the starter.  It is running and I took it for a drive with the ground wire detached.

Would could the problem be?  Something else is grounding the motor?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It seems strange to me the starter would have a ground wire directly to it, though it shouldn't matter one way or the other. The engine itself is usually grounded to the frame (in several placed). The ground from the battery should run out to the frame and to the engine itself. What you are describing is very strange indeed!

Comment: Surely the starter motor shouldn't have it's own ground wire as what usually happens is the starer grounds through the engine / gearbox and this is the circuit that is made only when the solenoid is activated.  The starter spins whilst it's "grounded" by design and the solenoid is responsible from making / breaking this connection.

Comment: Hi Paul and Steve thanks for the responses.  On this F150 the main engine ground wire runs to one of the mounting bolts for the starter. I know on other cars the starter grounds directly to the engine or via grounding strap to the engine, but Ford had a better idea. Right now the only wire coming from my negative battery terminal in going to the body because the main wire to the engine is disconnected.